# can we fill the ImageView based on Content description

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new to coding, I have some ImageViews with content description.
I have to fill the ImageViews with some specific background color only using content description of ImageViews. And I don't need to use the resource id's in this.
Please help me.

**Here is my sample ImageView**

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/iv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="iv"/>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: you can get resource id via id

Comment: You need to use resource id at least to declare your image views in activity, then you can check content description by using this id as getContentDescription and  compare it and fill as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

1: you can use "#....",and use `Color.parseColor(ImageView.getContentDescription())`

2: you can getID by "sourceName"

```
Resources res = getResources();
final String packageName = getPackageName();
int imageResId = res.getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "drawable", packageName);
int imageResIdByAnotherForm = res.getIdentifier(packageName + ":drawable/ic_launcher", null, null);

int musicResId = res.getIdentifier("test", "raw", packageName);

int notFoundResId = res.getIdentifier("activity_main", "drawable", packageName);
```